# SplitviewController in navigationviewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hey I am building my first ios application using xcode. I'm a total noob in xcode and swift and I am trying to use the storyboards to set-up my app. Here's a link to the prototype http://adobe.ly/1q5Imf6.

Basically my issue is where I want to do the split view on the resellers page. I want to use the splitviewcontroller only on the page, so after an intro viewcontroller in a navigation controller. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjICn.png)
I read somewhere that a splitviewcontroller must be the initial view controller, however this works if I use segues that pop up modally. But when I do that I don't really have a navigation bar anymore on the page. I only have the splitview, but there must be the option to go back.

Am I doing this completely wrong or is there a simple fix to get what I want?

Comment: If Apple states, that an `UISplitViewController` must be the initial view controller you (especially as a beginner) should not do it anyways. This way, you are just asking for pain. You should rather build your own split view controller or use a different UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present your `UISplitViewController` modally, then you need to wrap into `UINavigationController`. After it you can add `UIBarButtonItem` in your `UISplitViewController` and set an action to `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

[image: Storyboard implementation]